# i don't know why a very basic code related to socket is causing problem

Tags: c++, sockets, winsock2

It's a socket communication code that I've been using for a long time, but a few days ago, I tried to wrap it up but it didn't work at all. I checked setting of the port number of inbound rules but it doesn't work. so I'm asking you this question

If setting ip to 127.0.0.1 and run each two files on the same pc, there will be no communication problem. But the problem is that if I run the server and the client file on the two different networks, I get 10060 error

I checked the public ip of each pc several times and checked the port setting several times in the inbound rule. And I thought it was an individual problem with the PC, so I tried it with 6 different PCs, but the results were the same. It's a very basic code, but I don't know which part has a problem because there is an error.

this is my server code and client code

**Server**

```
#define _WINSOCK_DEPRECATED_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <WinSock2.h>
#pragma comment(lib,"ws2_32")

#define PORT 10168
#define PACKET_SIZE 1024

using namespace std;

void ConnectSocket();

char* ClientIndex;
SOCKET hc = NULL;
SOCKET hListen;
SOCKADDR_IN tListenAddr = {};

int main()
{
    ClientIndex = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * 128);
    ClientIndex = (char*)"123.456.789.123";

    WSADATA wsaData;
    WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaData);

    
    hListen = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);

    
    tListenAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    tListenAddr.sin_port = htons(PORT);
    tListenAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);

    
    bind(hListen, (SOCKADDR*)&tListenAddr, sizeof(tListenAddr));
    
    listen(hListen, 20);
    
    for (;;)
    {
        ConnectSocket();

        if (hc != NULL)
        {   
            cout << "success" << endl;
            break;
        }
        Sleep(200);
    }
}

void ConnectSocket()
{
    
    SOCKADDR_IN tCIntAddr = {};
    int iCIntSize = sizeof(tCIntAddr);
    SOCKET hclient = accept(hListen, (SOCKADDR*)&tCIntAddr, &iCIntSize);

    if (!strcmp(inet_ntoa(tCIntAddr.sin_addr), ClientIndex))
    {       
        hc = hclient;
    }
    hclient = NULL;
    return;
}
```

**Client**

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <WinSock2.h>
#include "windows.h"
#include <ws2tcpip.h>

#pragma comment(lib,"ws2_32")

#define PORT 10168
#define PACKET_SIZE 1024
#define SERVER_IP "123.456.123.456"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    WSADATA wsaData;
    WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaData);

    SOCKET hSocket;
    hSocket = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
 

    SOCKADDR_IN tAddr = {};
    tAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    tAddr.sin_port = htons(PORT);
    tAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(SERVER_IP);

    if (connect(hSocket, (sockaddr*)&tAddr, sizeof(tAddr)) == -1)
        cout << "connect fail : " << GetLastError()  << endl;

}
```

Comment: Does it work on the local host with both client and server side by side, but both using the eth0 bound IP on said-host rather than the loopback address ? Prolly should include that in your question. A timeout seems weird in this example..

Comment: `_WINSOCK_DEPRECATED_NO_WARNINGS` is probably not smart, it could tell you things. Generally, don't use macros in order to define constants and don't use C-style casts. Consider asking for a code review at codereview.stackexchange.com, make sure to read the site guidelines there first though.

Answer (score 0):

I solve it.
problem is port forwarding setting of router

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).